# How to redirect users based on IP address on initial load in Gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-cookies, gatsby, session-storage

I'm trying to build a gatsby(react based) website that auto-redirect users to different language index pages based on their IP addresses.

Below is my code structure:

layout.en.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

class Layout extends Component {
 state = {countryCode: ''}

  componentWillMount() {
    this.getIp()
  }

  getIp = () => {
    axios
      .get('https://ipapi.co/json/')
      .then(response => {
        let data = response.data
        this.setState({
          countryCode: data.country_code,
        })
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
render(){
    if (this.state.countryCode === 'CN') {
      window.location = '/cn/'
    }
} return 
(...)
}
```

The problem with the above setup is that users won't be able to switch back to the English site, it will keep on redirecting them every time when they try to visit the default index page. I understand that I might need to implement a cookie or session storage to solve the issue, but I'm not sure how. It'd be great if someone can help walk me through the process.